# Automated Yahoo Mail login with cURL - how?

Tags: php, curl

I am currently attempting to create a page with cURL instructions that does the following:

Take the following link, send a GET request to it, and retrieve the results.

http://login.yahoo.com/config/login?login=xxxxxxx&passwd=yyyyyyyy&.done=http://m.yahoo.com/mail

xxxxx - username
yyyyy - password

Easy, right? Not really. Since the page that is to be returned, is designed to automatically log you in your Yahoo Mail inbox.

I tried with:

```
<?php

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://login.yahoo.com/config/login?login=xxxxxx&passwd=yyyyyyy&.done=http://m.yahoo.com/mail',
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'something-here'
));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

echo $resp;

?>
```

I do get a response, but all it's about is the Yahoo Mail login page. It doesn't actually execute the login and retrieve the related Yahoo inbox.

How would I go about doing that with cURL?

Comment: Did you actually set a user-agent? or did you leave it as 'Something-here'

Comment: Yes, I did. That is not it.

Comment: Yahoo's signin page is chock full of extra fields and methods to prevent you from doing this. It's never going to work.

Comment: Did you add curlopt_followredirects to the options?

Comment: You mean curlopt_followlocation. Yes, I did. No effect. Should I also set cookie options?

Comment: And yes. set cookie options.

Comment: @Sammitch It did work. Answer is below.

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive testing.. I decided to see as why this was not working and I was interested in @Sammitch's comment that it won't work..

I first tried using my own HTTP Requests class to login and I failed. the response always stayed empty but if I visited the URL from my browser it would work. I turned on the developer tools in Chrome and went to the network section and tried logging in

It seemed that that page posted the data into another page which is

> http://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?login=xxxxxx&passwd=yyyyyy&.done=http://m.yahoo.com/mail

After altering my cURL code to work with that URL directly it signed me in.. so this is the solution to your question.. basically the URL you were using did not work and the one that should work is shown above.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit? I tried substituting the URL with the new one, filling in the respective data, but all I'm getting now is a blank page.

Comment: These are the following options that I set.. CURLOPT_URL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, CURLOPT_REFERER, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, and CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.. are all these set in your request?

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://212.233.xxx.xxx/curl.php',
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?login=&passwd=jungle&.done=http://m.yahoo.com/mail',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7',
 CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt'

Comment: Is it still returning an empty response?

Comment: Can't figure out how to send the reply with proper code tags to enclose the php code in... Are the above ones correct?

Comment: Yes, it is returning a blank page. Cookie.txt and cookies.txt are writable, since I am testing this on my home Win machine.

Comment: Do you have somewhere where I can contact you? I don't wanna turn the comments into a chatroom.

Comment: Of course - my email is "bozaaaa@abv.bg". Alternatively, I am always running Skype: Skype ID is "ionicles".

Comment: Skype's bugging out for some reason, not delivering messages. Trying to call you.